# Need help adding multiple functions to one VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have some code that I learnt from Stack Overflow that finds specific text in a .txt file and replaces it with different text. In the code below it looks for the number '14' and replaces it with '8'. I'm pretty sure I understand how this code works after reading around this forum, so thanks for that.

Where I'm stuck is I then want it to repeat the process looking for a different number and replacing it but I can't figure out how to add a second function into the same set of code. I'm assuming it needs an 'if' or a 'do' but I'm a total beginner. Happy to learn anything you have.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "C:\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"14")> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"14","8")
    End If 
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop
```

Comment: The `If` block is not necessary. You could get rid of it and then add `strLine = Replace(strLine,"differentNumber","replacement")` right after `strLine = Replace(strLine,"14","8")`.

Comment: This work perfectly. Makes total sense. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to re-using code `Function` and `Sub` are your friend.

- `Function` will allow to pass arguments and return a result.
- `Sub` procedures allow to pass arguments.

In this case I would create a `Sub` to process the manipulated file and pass in the arguments it needs to manipulate it, as you have nothing to return.

```vb
Sub ReplaceValueInFile(file, search, replace)
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile = file
    Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine, search)> 0 Then
            strLine = Replace(strLine, search, replace)
        End If 
        WScript.Echo strLine
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can then call the `Sub` in code using;

```vb
Call ReplaceValueInFile("C:\File.txt", "14", "8")
```

But now it’s reusable, you can change the input file, the search string and the replace string in the procedure arguments;

```vb
Call ReplaceValueInFile("C:\NewFile.txt", "20", "2")
```

Comment: It's great that you explained reusable functions (which the OP kind of asked about) but I would advise against this approach to solve the OP's problem. There's really no need to reopen the file and re-iterate its lines just to replace another string.

Comment: @41686d6564 I wasn’t going to refactor their code, they asked how it could be re-usable so I stuck to explaining the concepts. We are not here to rewrite their code for them, just give them a starting point. It also entirely depends what they will be doing, that shows the flexibility of being able to specify a completely different file for instance.

Comment: @41686d6564 end of the day there are 100 ways to skin this I was trying to keep the concept of reusability simple. You could pass in a collection of strings to search and values to replace them for example. Still believe reusable code is the way to go.

Comment: _"Still believe reusable code is the way to go"_ Well, yes but `Replace()` is what should be reused here :) See my comment under the question.

Comment: @41686d6564 Look i’m not debating this with you i’ve worked with VBScript for many years, don’t need you telling what is and isn’t reusable. What you’re suggesting is just add another replace line and change the search and replace value which is a valid approach for a one off but it isn’t what I’d class as reusable.

Comment: `call` is from BASIC for DOS and does nothing in Windows. It is there to help porting DOS programs to Windows.

Comment: I ended up using code removing the IF statements in the end but really appreciate you explaining the Sub and Call functions. I was not aware of these.

Comment: @user14797724 `Call` is useful because it allows to use a `Sub` procedure with parentheses. It's a stylistic thing not for everyone, just prefer code like `Call ReplaceValueInFile("C:\NewFile.txt", "20", "2")` to `ReplaceValueInFile "C:\NewFile.txt", "20", "2"`.

Comment: It's purpose is to call assembly language functions in MS-DOS programs. Assembly language cannot return a value in BASIC. So you pass in a out Param as an in Param.

Comment: @user14797724 [Not in VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/wcx04ck5(v=vs.84)) - "Transfers control to a Sub or Function procedure."

Comment: Yes in VBScript for porting MS-DOS to windows. Where is the sense of calling 2 function calls to call 1 function.

Comment: Honestly, in no VBScript documentation have I ever seen `Call` used in reference to porting MS-DOS to Windows (maybe in BASIC perhaps). Fact is in VBScript; "The purpose of the Call statement when used with a Sub is to allow you to enclose the argument list in parentheses." and nothing more.